# Duplicated declarations in compiled out-file using Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to compile two ES6 files into a single ES5 output file using Babel. The resulting file seems to contain DUPLICATED declarations like:

```
var _createClass = function () { ... }
```

and

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {value: true});
```

Here are the files:

File1 (./ec6/ec6Class.js)

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(dep1, dep2) {

    }

    foo() {
        console.log('foo')
    }
}
```

File 2 (./ec6/ec6Class2.js)

```
import MyClass from './ec6Class';

export class MyClass2 extends MyClass {
    constructor(dep1, dep2) {
        super(dep1, dep2)
    }

    bar() {
        console.log('bar')
    }
}
```

My Babel CLI command is:

```
babel src/client/ec6 --out-file script-compiled.js
```

How do I compile the two file to a single file with single declarations of the Babel infrastructure? Having duplicated declarations is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: You can use external helpers for this purpose.. https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/external-helpers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are telling Babel to compile all files it finds in `src/client/ec6`, while what you want is a single point of entry (in fact,  you already have that). <s>Babel will compile ec6Class.js once because it's a file in that directory, and then a second time because it's imported in ec6Class2.js.</s>

Try with

`babel src/client/ec6/ec6Class2.js --out-file script-compiled.js`

**EDIT**
Sorry I answered too fast. In fact, Babel is meant to simply transpile a javascript file from a cutting edge version of ES to a more compatible one. What you need is to combine it with [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), a tool that "packs" your multiple javascript files into one (it can minify them as well).

You can use Webpack from the command line and tell it to use Babel to transpile your files first. For a good getting started guide you can read [Webpack — The Confusing Parts](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpack-the-confusing-parts-58712f8fcad9) on Medium.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't do it. The resulting file will contain the line `var _ec6Class = require('./ec6Class');` which is relying on having the ec6Class in some file scope. The goal here is to have everything in the same file, a REAL self contained code that can execute in a single file

Comment: I added webpack to the project, configured it to merge and Bable like you said. It worked great for me. Thank you!